# Sublime text, search and replace to add new space in stylesheets

Tags: html, css, regex, replace, sublimetext2

I am trying to find a way to search and replace in multiple files against the following situation:

```
.selector{
```

So that it becomes:

```
.selector {
```

Is there any regex or other method of finding a lack of space following by curly bracket?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically need `regex` to solve your problem

Comment: Not specifically, just an idea.

Comment: In SublimeText, you may try a regex replacement: find `(\.\w+)\{` and replace with `$1 {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this. Use this:

**Step 1:** Find for `{` and replace with `(space){`.
**Step 2:** Now replace all `(space)(space){` with `(space){`.

**Note:** Replace the `(space)` with a real space character.

Comment: This worked well, for it's simplicity this is the most functional method, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you to use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify package to format you HTML/CSS/JS code properly.

You can install this package using `Package Control` and configure it.

You'll first need to install Node.js to use this package.

---

If you want to use `regex`

Find       ----    `\b([.#\d\w-]*?)\{`

Replace By ----    `$1 {`

Comment: I have prettify, however this is for multiple (lots!) files and the plugin requires each file to open and worked upon individually. Thanks.

Comment: NodeJS? What crazy thing? I am also using Package Control, but without NodeJS.

Comment: @PraveenKumar For this package, you'll need Node.Js

Comment: @Alex I've added Regex solution, kindly check it

Comment: Thanks very much Tushar, this is a great option but for simplicity's sake the additional space technique from @Praveen Kumar is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

there is a replace method:
http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html

Just cheat on it:
First replace all '{' with ' {' (all brackets into one space)
Then replace all '  {' with ' {' (double spaced into one space)

Answer (score 0):

RegExp solution:

Match any non-whitespace character followed by curly bracket:

```
(\S)\{
```

Insert space in between of character and bracket, replace string:

```
$1 {
```